# Simplify 12 SQL statements to 2 statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL script which I have to simplify but I don't know how... I'm pretty new to SQL.

The statements are:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role WHERE name = 'lettersOfGuarantee')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [permissions].[role] (name, description, assignable, editable, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
    VALUES ('lettersOfGuarantee','Εγγυητικές Επιστολές', 1, 1,'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'chequesInCollaterals')
              AND customer_category = 1 AND user_category = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl] (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
        SELECT id, 1, 1, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        FROM [permissions].[role] 
        WHERE name = 'chequesInCollaterals';
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'lettersOfGuarantee')
                        AND customer_category = 1 AND user_category = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl] (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 1, 1, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] 
            WHERE name = 'lettersOfGuarantee';
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'chequesInCollaterals')
AND customer_category = 2 AND user_category = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 1, 2, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'chequesInCollaterals';
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'lettersOfGuarantee')
AND customer_category = 2 AND user_category = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 1, 2, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'lettersOfGuarantee';
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'chequesInCollaterals')
AND customer_category = 3 AND user_category = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 1, 3, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'chequesInCollaterals';
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'lettersOfGuarantee')
AND customer_category = 3 AND user_category = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 1, 3, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'lettersOfGuarantee';
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'chequesInCollaterals')
AND customer_category = 3 AND user_category = 2)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 2, 3, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'chequesInCollaterals';
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'lettersOfGuarantee')
AND customer_category = 3 AND user_category = 2)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 2, 3, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'lettersOfGuarantee';
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'chequesInCollaterals')
AND customer_category = 4 AND user_category = 2)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 2, 4, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'chequesInCollaterals';
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'lettersOfGuarantee')
AND customer_category = 4 AND user_category = 2)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 2, 4, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'lettersOfGuarantee';
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'chequesInCollaterals')
AND customer_category = 5 AND user_category = 2)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 2, 5, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'chequesInCollaterals';
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM permissions.role_category_rl where role_id = (select id from permissions.role where name = 'lettersOfGuarantee')
AND customer_category = 5 AND user_category = 2)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
            (role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
            SELECT id, 2, 5, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'lettersOfGuarantee';
END
GO
```

Since only the user_category, customer_category values are changing we must declare a list:

```
DECLARE @categories table (customer_cat_id BIGINT, user_cat_id BIGINT);
INSERT INTO @categories
  VALUES (1, 1),
         (1, 2),
         (1, 3),
         (2, 4),
         (2, 5),
         (2, 6);
```

I don't know how i can modify the two variables dynamically.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Are you trying to create an SP with 2 params and executed multiple times?

Comment: I'm trying to simlify the above script which contains 12 statements into two statments. If you see in the 12 statements the only thing that change is the  SELECT id, 1, 1, SELECT id, 1, 2 etc. We somehow need to change this to be dynamic from the @categories

Comment: I removed the `plsql` tag as that is for Oracle and the code in your question is clearly for Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Is it me, or does the categories columns / values don't align with the rest of the queries? The way you're requesting the customer_category and user_category values in your queries seem to be swapped in the categories temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the table variable that you have created in your select to project the user_category and customer_category:

```
INSERT INTO [permissions].[role_category_rl]
(role_id, user_category, customer_category, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date)
SELECT id, cat.user_cat_id, cat.customer_cat_id, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'V4.69.sql', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM @categories cat, [permissions].[role] WHERE name = 'lettersOfGuarantee';
```

Comment: @user7334203, does that solves your issue? To be honest, I don't know for sure if I could really understand your question.